# Visual Studio Code for Hack IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hhvm, hacklang

What do you think about visual studio code for programming Hack? If so, Why? I'm asking because of his method of syntax error system and because I can’t find basic information about this language.

I saw that visual studio code and vim were the only ones but I thought if you guys have another one so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, [vscode-hack](https://github.com/slackhq/vscode-hack) by slack is the unofficial-official hack extension.

Previously, Facebook created their own Hack/React IDE based on Atom ( https://nuclide.io/ ), sadly, the project has been archived, and now, VS Code is recommended.

You can learn more about how to setup your development environment for vs code here : https://github.com/slackhq/vscode-hack

If you are just getting started with Hack, see the following links :

- https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/getting-started/getting-started
- https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/getting-started/getting-started